# iPhone - Setting an icon AND a text into a UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, fonts, uibutton

Is there a way to display **into the text** label of a UILabel an "ANY icon + text", assuming that the icon is an Apple symbol or Zapf Dingbats font caracter ?

That way localizing the text would automaticaly center the whole thing and adjust the icon position into the label depending on its size.

Something like this : http://www.chocolatechip-ui.com/screenshots/buttons.png
I would have an image for the background and overlay onto it the icon+text label.

**I DON'T** want to put an image in a button.

**EDIT**
I limit the question just for UILabel as asking the same thing to work for UIButton generate lots of out of context answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the UIButton style to custom and set the icon image as Background (not image), you will be able to see the title when you set it.

Comment: You can align the text at the right of the icon from the alignment section of the control attributes inspector.

Comment: That's not the question. I don't want to align anything by hand.

Comment: Hello, I made a mistake. Can you please edit your answer to "unlock" it please ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this swift project: https://github.com/anatoliyv/SMIconLabel If you could put your symbol into UIImage it should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with attributedText (iOS >= 7)

```
NSTextAttachment *attachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
attachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];

NSAttributedString *attachmentString = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:attachment];

NSMutableAttributedString *myString= [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]     initWithString:@"text bla bla bla"];
[myString appendAttributedString:attachmentString];

self.label.attributedText = myString;
```

Answer (score -1):

You could create a view which suites your needs and overlay a custom invisible button.

As an alternative you could subclass `UIButton`.

Comment: That does not seem to match the question, or you should detail a little bit more. Making "something" that cover my needs does not help.

Comment: I thought you know how to add subview to views. It's just `addSubview`. The rest should be obvious.

Comment: Ok, but even if I add a subview, that does not tell me how I may display the icon as text.

Answer (score -1):

try: `label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];`

Comment: Ouuch, this is really tricky  :-) ! I'll try a little bit later. Did you try it ?